# Reset Customer password through Database

Tags: magento2, customer, password, reset

I want to reset one of my customer's password through database. What is the query for this in magento 2.

Comment: @Nafisha Did you able to update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to execute this query in your database :

```
UPDATE `customer_entity` SET `password_hash` = SHA2('admin123', 256) WHERE `entity_id` = 1;
```

or

```
UPDATE `customer_entity` SET `password_hash` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxadmin123', 256), ':xxxxxxx:1') WHERE `entity_id` = 1;
```

- replace value of password instead of **admin123**
- replace value of **xxxxxxx** with crypt key.

You can get crypt key from **app/etc/env.php** file

```
<?php
return array (
  ...
  'crypt' => 
  array (
    'key' => 'c51288337454ecab8280de9989b7624d',
  ),
  ...
```

From admin panel,

You can click on "**Reset Password**" in customer edit form. Mail will be sent on appropriate email ID. Then, you can reset password.

> **Note : Take backup of your db before execute.**

Comment: Thanx. Is there any way for admin to change customer's password from admin panel?

Comment: I update sql query and answer also. Please check it.

Comment: Mail is sent to customer's email id. I dont want that. I want to reset password on my own

Comment: Okay. Then, you can't able to update from admin panel. You need to execute query in DB.

Comment: ok, Is it possible to change the email to mine, then after resetting the password, again change the email to customers?

Comment: You need to change it by CSV using this https://theecommmanager.com/reset-customer-password-magento-2/ if you want to avoid SQL query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105428/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-nafisa).

Comment: it worked through db.Thanx

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding !! :)

Answer (score 0):

This SQL works just fine to update the customer password.

Just change **YOURPASSWORD** below (keep the xxx:es)

```
'UPDATE `customer_entity`
SET `password_hash` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxYOURPASSWORD', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1')
WHERE `entity_id` = 1;'
```